# is there a way to get FactoryBoy to pass a parameter to the save() method of my Django model?

Tags: factory-boy

I have a Django model like this:

```
class NicePerson(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, make_irish=False, *args, **kwargs):
        """if make_irish is True, prepend last_name with O'"
        if make_irish:
            self.last_name = "O'" + self.last_name

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I have a FactoryBoy class to build NicePerson instances

```
class NicePersonFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = NicePerson
```

I know I can use these together like so:

```
nice_person = NicePersonFactory(last_name='Shea')
```

But how can I pass the "make_irish" parameter to my `save()` method?

Answer (score 6):

factory_boy uses the default manager for creation, i.e it calls `NicePerson.objects.create()` or `NicePerson.objects.get_or_create()`.

For your example, you could override those managers (in your Model definition):

```
class NicePersonManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('make_irish', False):
            kwargs.update(...)
        return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
```

Another option would be to override your factory's `_create` and `_get_or_create` methods. For instance:

```
class NicePersonFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        make_irish = kwargs.pop('make_irish', False)
        instance = model_class(**kwargs)
        instance.save(make_irish=make_irish)
        return instance
```